# Computing the value of a function whose derivative is another function

Tags: calculus

Apologies if this is something relatively trivial, my calculus is a bit rusty.

Let say I have function $f(t)$ which is increasing at a non-constant rate. This rate is also a function of $t$, lets say $g(t)$.

So I have the situation where $\frac{d f(t)}{dt} = g(t)$

The function $g(t)$ could be a linear one (i.e. $\frac{d g(t)}{dt}$ is constant), but it could also be in terms of some other function, which could be linear or defined in terms of some other similar function... and so on and so forth.

How do I go about calculating the value of $f(t)$ for a specific $t$, given that at $t=0$ I know the value of $f(t)$ and also of $g(t)$ and dependent variables?

Comment: What do you mean by dependent variables?

Comment: Do you know the value of $g(t)$ everywhere, or only at $t=0$? If you only know it at one point, you can't calculate the value elsewhere.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon By dependent variables I meant the functions on which $f(t)$ depends on. For example the state of charge of a battery depends on time spent charging and the temperature, but temperature also changes according to time.

Comment: @KSmarts Well I might need to compute $g(t)$ depending on some other function, but in the simplest case they will all boil down to a constant rate linear function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You integrate

$$f(t) = \int g(t) dt$$

which gives you the value of $f(t)$ to within an arbitrary constant.

Then use the particular values you know -- $f(0)$ should be enough -- to solve for the arbitrary constant.

Let's say $g(t) = t^2$ and $f(0) = 2$.  Then

$$f(t) = \int t^2 dt = \frac{t^3}{3} + C.$$

Now, since $f(0) = 2, C = 2,$ and the solution is $f(t) = (t^3/3) + 2.$

Comment: Cheers. So if $g(t)$ itself is also a function dependent on $h(t)$, I should start at the bottom, integrate each, until I arrive to the integral of $g(t)$. Am I on the right track?